# How to search Nagios by service?

Tags: nagios

I'm trying to search for Current Load across all my hosts but Nagios Quick Search returns nothing.  I've found [this thread](http://sourceforge.net/p/nagios/mailman/message/30543764/) about it possibly just searching host names or aliases.  Is there another way?

Answer (score 4):

After reading the source, I found that you can call status directly with a service filter to get Nagios search by service:

```
/status.cgi?servicefilter=Current%20Load
```

Comment: See https://raw.githubusercontent.com/lemenkov/nagios/master/cgi/status.c for other possibilities.

Answer (score 0):

Add to nagios/share/side.php next block after your navbarsearch(Quick Search):

```
<div class="navbarsearch">
<form method="get" action="<?php echo $cfg["cgi_base_url"];?>/status.cgi" target="<?php echo $link_target;?>">
 <fieldset>
   <legend>Service Search:</legend>
   <input type='text'   name='servicefilter' size='15' class="NavBarSearchItem">
 </fieldset>
</form>
```